# Guid property on Mysql Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using Entity Framework with MySql extension on ASP.NET Core application. One of my domain model `Message` have Guid property and when I want to execute any operation on my DbContext I'm receiving an error: `The property 'Message.ID' is of type 'Guid' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or manually configure the database type for it.`.

How do I "manually configure the database type'? I've read that it should be mapped for CHAR(36), but I couldn't find how to do that on application side.

@UPDATE

When I set the attribute `[Column(TypeName = "char(32)")]` to the `Guid` property, error remains.

This method also does not work

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  var messageEntity = modelBuilder.Entity< Message>();
  messageEntity.Property(x => x.ID).
   HasAnnotation("Column", new { TypeName = "char(32)" });
}
```

Comment: You should use `char(32)` or wider field in DB and in EF `string`, for storing GUID.  You can update the table using EF update database wizard or can make manual changes to the EF db XML file. Change guid to string and in table structure to  char(36).

Comment: Is there any way to define Guid as `char(32)` or `binary(16)` for MySql? So I could use Guid in my application without any wrappers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this issue and I resolved that way:

1. I removed the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore from my project
2. I installed [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) by `Nuget` and this
   data provider mapped correctly the `Guid`.
3. I changed my method name `UseMySQL` to `UseMySql` and added `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`  at `Startup.cs`:

---

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>               
options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")));
```

Remember to make sure the `Guid` is data type `char(36)` in the database.

Comment: a mix of information from different sources and a little patience to try ;)

Comment: Which data type does the CHAR(36) map to in POCO class property? Is it `Guid` or `String`?

Comment: You can use Guid

Comment: char(36) for Guid is inefficient use BINARY(16) instead

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully used the `Guid` type with MySql EF in regular ASP.NET (not Core) with the Database First approach.

To accomplish this, I've defined the column type in MySql as `BINARY(16)`.
It's been quite a while since I've developed that model, but I think I remember that MySql EF provider automatically maps `BINARY(16)` to `System.Guid` in the EF models.

You will have to use the `oldguids=true` connection string property so that MySql uses the `BINARY(16)` type for guids instead of the default `CHAR(36)`.

I also think that making the column `CHAR(36)` and skipping the `oldguids=true` part in the connection string would also result in the same thing.

Comment: I have added `oldguids=true` to the connection string but nothing changed. I want to solve this problem but using code first. Thanks for your response